# How to calculate and set the new position of a QGraphicsItem relative to a new parent's origin?

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

**Question**

*How to calculate and set the new position of a QGraphicsItem relative to a new parent's origin?*

**Background Information**

I am developing a resizing feature that brings up a bounding box with one anchor upon double-clicking on a given object (rectangle, ellipse, etc.). The user can resize the object by adjusting the position of the anchor.

**What is Working**

The user can double click on the object and resize fine, on first resizing attempt.

**Problematic Observations**

On consecutive resizing attempts (passes), the user sees the object "jumping" (i.e., suddenly resizing) immediately after double-clicking on the object and moving the anchor ever so slightly. *The object does not suddenly resize to any position, but exactly to the position of the previous parent.*

**Towards a Root Cause**

I have narrowed down the problem to the following statement (snippet from our overloaded mousemoveevent() function):

```
dynamic_cast<RIShape*>(_item)->scaleBy(myp, xscale, yscale);
```

**Reference to an Online Posting Describing a Similar Problem**

As I looked around a little bit, prior to posting this message, I came across the following reference:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/22775-Qgraphicsitem-parent-child-paint-problem

Judging from this message, I needed to calculate and set the new position of the QGraphicsItem (_item) relative to a new parent's origin. Hence, the question above.

P.S. Here are additional code snippets, in case you are interested:

*Method of Creating the Resizer (Bounding Box with an Anchor) and Tying to the Object to be Resized*

```
QGraphicsItem* item = itemAt( event->pos() );
RIShape*       shape= dynamic_cast<RIShape*>(item);
if( item && shape )
{
  if( !_selector )
  {
    _selector = new RISelector(item);
...
```

*Method of Initializing the Constructor for the Resizer (RISelector)*

```
  RISelector(QGraphicsItem* item)
  : QGraphicsRectItem(item->sceneBoundingRect()), _W(10.0),
    _rect(item->sceneBoundingRect()), _pivot(0,0), _pressed(false), _isResizing(false),
  _bndBoxPen(Qt::black, 2, Qt::DashLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin),
  _anchorPen(Qt::black, 2, Qt::SolidLine), _item(item), _isLef(false)
```